# Is there a way to tell via REST if an Azure VM is started or not?

Tags: rest, azure, virtual-machine

I have a couple of Persistent VMs in Azure that I want to programmatically Start/Stop under certain circumstances. But they my have been started or stopped manually.

Is there a way I can tell via the REST API if the VM is started or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could invoke [`Get Deployment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460804.aspx) operation (it would work on your Persistent VMs as well) which would give you deployment status using which you can decide you need to perform an operation on your VM.

```
class Program
    {
        static string subscriptionId = "subscription id";
        static string certificateData = "Data from ManagementCertificate node in publish setting file ";
        static string cloudServiceName = "name of the cloud service";
        static X509Certificate2 cert = null;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            cert = new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(certificateData));
            Test2();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void Test2()
        {
            string endpoint = string.Format("https://management.core.windows.net/{0}/services/hostedservices/{1}/deploymentslots/production", subscriptionId, cloudServiceName);
            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(endpoint);
            req.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
            req.ContentType = "application/xml";
            req.Headers.Add("x-ms-version", "2013-03-01");
            req.Method = "GET";
            try
            {
                using (var resp = req.GetResponse())
                {
                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
                    {
                        var responseData = sr.ReadToEnd();
                        Console.WriteLine(responseData);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (WebException webEx)
            {
                using (var resp = webEx.Response)
                {
                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
                    {
                        var errorDetails = sr.ReadToEnd();
                        Console.WriteLine(errorDetails);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can't seem to get it to work. If I use services/hostedservices/{0}/deployments/{1} I get no useful information and if I use services/hostedservices/{0}/deploymentslots/{1} with staging or production I get <Code>ResourceNotFound</Code>. Do you know how I should call it?

Comment: Hmm...that's weird. I tried it with a console application and I got the proper response back. I have updated my response with the code that I used.

Comment: Thanks heaps. I was using very similar code to you but when yours worked I tried a few more tests and I found that I was passing the instance name rather than the service name.